# How to get mean, median, and other statistics over entire matrix, array or dataframe?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dataframe, r-faq

I know this is a basic question but for some strange reason I am unable to find an answer.

How should I apply basic statistical functions like mean, median, etc. over entire array, matrix or dataframe to get unique answers and not a vector over rows or columns

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since this comes up a fair bit, I'm going to treat this a little more comprehensively, to include the 'etc.' piece in addition to `mean` and `median`.

1. For a matrix, or array, as the others have stated, `mean` and `median` will return a single value. However, `var` will compute the covariances between the columns of a two dimensional matrix. Interestingly, for a multi-dimensional array, `var` goes back to returning a single value. `sd` on a 2-d matrix will work, but is deprecated, returning the standard deviation of the columns. Even better, `mad` returns a single value on a 2-d matrix *and* a multi-dimensional array. If you *want* a single value returned, the safest route is to coerce using `as.vector()` first. Having fun yet?
2. For a `data.frame`, `mean` is deprecated, but will again act on the columns separately. `median` requires that you coerce to a vector first, or `unlist`. As before, `var` will return the covariances, and `sd` is again deprecated but will return the standard deviation of the columns. `mad` requires that you coerce to a vector or `unlist`. In general for a `data.frame` if you want something to act on all values, you generally will just `unlist` it first.

Edit: Late breaking news(): In R 3.0.0 mean.data.frame is defunctified:

```
o   mean() for data frames and sd() for data frames and matrices are
defunct.
```

Answer (score 19):

By default, `mean` and `median` etc work over an entire array or matrix.

E.g.:

```
# array:
m <- array(runif(100),dim=c(10,10))
mean(m) # returns *one* value.

# matrix:
mean(as.matrix(m)) # same as before
```

For data frames, you can coerce them to a matrix first (the reason this is by default over columns is because a dataframe can have columns with strings in it, which you can't take the mean of):

```
# data frame
mdf <- as.data.frame(m)
# mean(mdf) returns column means
mean( as.matrix(mdf) ) # one value.
```

Just be careful that your dataframe has all numeric columns before coercing to matrix. Or exclude the non-numeric ones.

Comment: But for dataframes, `mean` and `median` do not work as is. As you point out, coercing the df to matrix will error due to non-numeric columns (so you have to create a column index to only touch numeric columns). (Further, if the dataframe is large it isn't efficient or scalable to convert it with `as.matrix(mdf)` - big temporary variable).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `library dplyr` via install.packages('dplyr') and then

```
dataframe.mean <- dataframe %>%
  summarise_all(mean) # replace for median
```