# Why does var act like cov in R?

Tags: r

Sorry to ask this ... it's surely a FAQ, and it's kind of a silly question, but it's been bugging me.  Suppose I want to get the variance of every numeric column in a dataframe, such as

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=seq(1,50,10))
```

Naturally, I try

```
var(df)
```

Instead of giving me what I'd hoped for, which would be something like

```
  x    y
2.5  250
```

I get this

```
     x   y
x  2.5  25
y 25.0 250
```

which has the variances in the diagonal, and covariances in other locations.  Which makes sense when I lookup help(var) and read that "var is just another interface to cov".  Variance is covariance between a variable and itself, of course.  The output is slightly confusing, but I can read along the diagonal, or generate only the variances using `diag(var(df))`, `sapply(df, var)`, or `lapply(df, var)`, or by calling `var` repeatedly on `df$x` and `df$y`.

But why?  Variance is a routine, basic descriptive statistic, second only to mean.  Shouldn't it be completely and totally trivial to apply it to columns of a dataframe?  Why give me the covariances when I only asked for variances?  Just curious.  Thanks for any comments on this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9424311/324364) question might also make for some good reading.

Answer (score 10):

The idiomatic approach is

```
sapply(df, var)
```

`var`  <s>has a method for `data.frames` which</s>  deals with `data.frames` by coercing  to a `matrix`.

`Variance` is a routine basic descriptive statistic, so are covariances and correlations. They are all interlinked and interesting , especially if you are aiming to use a linear model.

You could always create your own function to perform as you want

```
Var  <- function(x,...){
  if(is.data.frame(x)) {
   return(sapply(x, var,...))} else { return(var(x,...))}
}
```

Comment: It may be a little confusing to say that `var` has a method for data frames; it doesn't in the usual R sense of the word method (an S3 or S4 method). data frames are simply converted to matrices and then `cov` applied.

Comment: Thank you mnel, GavinSimpson, SimonO101.  These are all very helpful answers, as is joran's link--so that although I've voted them all up, I'm unwilling to mark one as _the_ answer.  I get it.

Answer (score 9):

This is documented in `?var`, namely:

```
Description:

     ‘var’, ‘cov’ and ‘cor’ compute the variance of ‘x’ and the
     covariance or correlation of ‘x’ and ‘y’ if these are vectors.  If
     ‘x’ and ‘y’ are matrices then the covariances (or correlations)
     between the columns of ‘x’ and the columns of ‘y’ are computed.
```

where by "matrices" the text means objects of class `"matrix"` and `"data.frame"`.

`var` doesn't have a method for data frames in the conventional sense. `var` simply coerces the input data frame to a matrix via `as.matrix` and then calls `cov` on that matrix.

In response to the question why, well I guess that the variance is closely related to the concept of covariance and to keep code simple R Core wrote a single implementation for the covariance of a matrix-like object and used this for the variance as that is the most likely thing you want from a matrix.

*Or more succinctly; that is how R Core implemented this. Learn to live with it. :-)*

Also note that R is moving away from having functions like `mean` and `sd` operate on the components (columns) of a data frame. If you want to apply any of these functions, including `var`, you are required to call something like:

```
apply(foo, 2, mean) ## for matrices
sapply(foo, mean) ## for data frames
```

or faster specific alternatives

```
colMeans(foo)
```

<strike>In this instance, I suspect that `diag(var(df))` will be the most efficient way to get the variances instead of calling `var` repeatedly via one of the `apply` family of functions.</strike> `diag(var(df))` is unlikely to be quicker than `sapply(df, var)` as the former has to compute all the covariances as well as the variances.

Comment: +1 and I've edited my response to note the lack of a conventional `method`

Comment: I was curious about whether diag(var(df)) or sapply(df, var) would be faster.  In this example: `df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(4*10^7), y=rbinom(4*10^7, 100, .5))`, `sapply(df,var)` takes about 1.8 seconds and increases R's RAM usage from about 1GB to 1.7GB during the operation, while `sapply(diag(var(df)))` takes about 4.5 seconds, and increases RAM from 1GB to about 2.5GB during the operation (R 2.15.0, MacBook Air 1.6GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB RAM, OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: @Mars No, you have that wrong. The entire call is `diag(var(df))`; you don't `sapply` it. As you show in your question `var(df)` returns the entire variance-covariance matrix of `df`. The bits you want are on the diagonal so we extract them with `diag()`. Anyway, I realise now that this way also computes the covariances so is likely slower than the `sapply` version.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I did run `diag(var(df))` without `sapply` (which wouldn't work, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

Your actual answer has been covered by @GavinSimpson. For `var` you could also just use:

```
sd(df)^2
# x     y 
# 2.5 250.0
```

And by doing so you will see what @GavinSimpson means about R "*moving away from having functions like `mean` and `sd` operate on the components (columns) of a data frame*". Deprecated means the functionality maybe be retired with an impending version change of R and your code may break if you dont heed the warning and change appropriately:

> Warning message:
>   sd() is deprecated.
>    Use sapply(*, sd) instead.

So we could use:

```
sapply(df,sd)^2
# x     y 
# 2.5 250.0
```

Which gives us the exact same result.

However, it's kinda silly to do it this way as you are effectively calling `(sqrt(var(x, na.rm = na.rm)))^2` on each column! Instead as @mnel suggests, `sapply( df , var)` is how you should  obtain the variance for each column vector.