# mean and sd from matrix out of CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, mean, standard-deviation

I want to calculate the mean and the sd from a matrix (14*20) that I import like this from a csv file:

```
data<- read.csv("data.csv",header=F,sep=";")
```

Why does this not work:
`sd(data)` and `mean(data)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424311/how-to-get-mean-median-and-other-statistics-over-entire-matrix-array-or-dataf see if this answers your question.

Comment: `read.csv` returns a data.frame, not a matrix. If you want the mean of all 280 numbers, you could do `mat <- data.matrix(data); mean(mat); sd(mat)`. If you intend to do column-wise means and sds then see the linked question by @goodtimeslim.