# mean of each matrix of an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, mean

I have to calculate mean of each matrix of an n dimension of array. As I am new in R can anyone help me.
For example

```
M = 4
m = array(1:10, dim= c(10, 1, M))
m
z = matrix(NA, M,1)
for (i in 1:z){
for (j in 1:z){
z[i, j] = mean(m[ , , i])
}
}
z
```

I tried above way but its incorrect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mean, median, and other statistics over entire matrix, array or dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424311/how-to-get-mean-median-and-other-statistics-over-entire-matrix-array-or-dataf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) apply** Try `apply`

```
apply(m, 3, mean)
## [1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

**2) loop** or to do it in a loop:

```
n <- dim(m)[3]
result <- numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n) result[i] <- mean(m[,,i])
result
## [1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

**3) reshape** or reshape it into a matrix and take the column means.  `n` is from above.

```
colMeans(matrix(m,, n))
## [1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `mean` function provides its answer in the form of a **1 x 1 matrix**, which I assume is what you're looking for since you didn't refer to a row-wise or column-wise mean.

Here is some detail on the topic from a previous post: [How to get mean, median, and other statistics over entire matrix, array or dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424311/how-to-get-mean-median-and-other-statistics-over-entire-matrix-array-or-dataf)

Comment: thanks but I am looking mean for per matrix wise in array as I have 4 matrix in above array so my output will be like mean of m[,,1], m[,,2], m[,,3], m[,,4]

Comment: I see, I modified a snippet your existing code to give you an element-wise mean for the array:                                                                                     
`z = matrix(NA, M,1)
for (i in 1:length(z)){
    z[i] = mean(m[, , i])
  }
z`